# How to sum foreach data

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code

```
@foreach($list['query'] as $wallet)
@php
if($wallet->item == 'ETH')
{
$url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$priceInfo = json_decode($data);
$marketprice1 = ($priceInfo[0]->current_price)*($wallet->primary_balance);
echo $marketprice1;
}

if($wallet->item == 'BTC')
{
$url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$priceInfo = json_decode($data);
$marketprice2 = ($priceInfo[0]->current_price)*($wallet->primary_balance);
echo $marketprice2;
}
@endphp
```

From above I get value (echo $marketprice1) = 1221 and (echo $marketprice2) = 23879
How to sum value 1 + value 2 ?
I try with this

```
echo $marketprice1+$marketprice2;
```

but not working, anyone can help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```php
@foreach($list['query'] as $wallet)
@php
$marketprice1 = 0;
$marketprice2 = 0;
if($wallet->item == 'ETH')
{
$url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=ethereum';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$priceInfo = json_decode($data);
$marketprice1 = ($priceInfo[0]->current_price)*($wallet->primary_balance);
echo $marketprice1;
}

if($wallet->item == 'BTC')
{
$url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$priceInfo = json_decode($data);
$marketprice2 = ($priceInfo[0]->current_price)*($wallet->primary_balance);
echo $marketprice2;
}

echo $marketprice1+$marketprice2;
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your script works (tried it without the if statements and set $wallet->primary_balance to 2). Could depend on the PHP version (7.4.5 here).

You could try

```
echo ($marketprice1+$marketprice2);
```

It should definitely work if you do it like

```
$sum = $marketprice1+$marketprice2;
echo $sum;
```

You should also initialize the price variables like seen in Andy Song's answer. Or even better:

```
$marketprice1 = 0.00;
$marketprice2 = 0.00;
```